# Excel formula depending on whether a cell is text or not

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

```
=IF(F46=0,I45-C46,I45-F46)
```

This works.  But now I want to include the following as well: Let's say `F46` is text – I want the cell value to be I45 (the previous cell value) but if it's not text I want it to be `I45-F46`.

Answer (score 5):

in cases like these, use [IS functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/is-functions-HP005209147.aspx):

```
=IF(F46=0,I45-C46,IF(ISTEXT(I46),I45,I45-F46))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this formula

```
=IF(F46=0,I45-C46,I45-N(F46))
```

`N` just returns the numeric value of any cell.

If the cell contains a text value it returns zero; so, if `A1 = 4` then `=N(A1)=4`, if `A1 = "x"` then `=N(A1)=0`.

Comment: What does `N( )` do?

Comment: Hello Tom - N just returns the numeric value of any cell - if the cell contains a text value it returns zero, so if A1 = 4 then =N(A1)=4, if A1 = "x" then =N(A1)=0